# Is "as much as" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, comparative-constructions

Is the following sentence correct and clear?

> The report shows that 7 to 10 years old children eat almost as much
> greasy food as 10 to 13-year-olds.

Is the following a better version? Does it mean exactly the same as the first one?

> The report shows that 7 to 10 years old children eat greasy food almost as much as 10 to 13-year-olds.

Comment: Both have a mistake: 7-to-10-year-old children. Year is singular. 10-to-13-year-old children and 10-to13-year-olds.

Answer (score 2):

These have different meanings. The first is comparing the quantity of food; the second could be talking about the amount, the frequency, the keenness, or some combination.